# How can I make sure that if the startdate column is null in the list view display the item anyway in the schema file

Tags: 2013, list-view, caml, schema

I have a list with 2 different views one that shows all items and one that shows current items.

But if startdate is null the item wont show up on current view. startdate should be nullable. How can i fix this?

In the schema file it looks like this:

```
    <Query>
      <Where>
        <And>
            <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name="StartDate"/>
            <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE">
              <Today />
            </Value>
          </Leq>
          <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
            <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE">
              <Today />
            </Value>
          </Geq>
        </And>
      </Where>
    </Query>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Or>
      <And>...</And>
      <IsNull>
        <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
      </IsNull>
    </Or>
  </Where>
</Query>
```